# inserting millions of xml files into basex

Tags: java, xml, basex

Is it possible to store a million of records(xml files) into Basex database?

```
for(int j=1;j<1000000;j++) {
     String id=String.valueOf(j);
     String[] elems={"firstname","lastname","nickname","salary","permanentAddress","currentAddress","contactNo","email","alternateMail","FacebookName","Color"};
     String[] childs = {id,"yong"+id,"mook kim"+id,"mkyong"+id,"100000"+id,"Bhopal"+id,"pune"+id,"999999999"+id ,"test"+id+"@basex.com","testA"+id+"@basex.com","Tom"+id,"grey"+id};

    try {
        xmlFile= x.CreateXMLDoc("test","transperfect",elems,childs);
    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException exception) { 
        exception.printStackTrace(); 
    }

    storeIntoBaseXDB(j,id,xmlFile);         
}
```

//StoreIntoBaseXDB method

public static void storeIntoBaseXDB(int i,String id,String xmlFile) throws BaseXException
    {

```
    if(i==1)
    {   
        System.out.println("=========================Store into Database=========================");


        //System.out.println("Check database existence");
        con.getDatabaseConnection(dbNmae);
        con.executeInsertQuery(dbNmae,id,xmlFile);
    }
    else
    {
        con.executeInsertQuery(dbNmae,id,xmlFile);

    }
}
```

//executeInsertQuery() method

```
          public long executeInsertQuery(String dbname,String id,String xmlFile) throws BaseXException
    {

           //System.out.println(path);
            new Open(dbname).execute(context);



            try 
            {


                /* String query = "db:add('db','C:/Users/manish/Desktop/BaseX65/xml/books.xml')";
                 QueryProcessor proc = new QueryProcessor(query, context);
                    proc.execute();
                    proc.close();
                    context.close();*/

                new Add(id,xmlFile).execute(context);

                //System.out.println(new Find(id));


            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("ERROR executing query: ");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Why wouldn't it be (a million is a relatively small number)?

The limit is 2^29 which is `546,870,912` (the number of stored XML documents).

The limit for XML elements is 2^31 which is `2,147,483,648` (although this includes all nodes including attributes, texts, etc.).

Here is a web page on BaseX statistics regarding example existing databases, the first row of the table also contains the limits (`#Files` represents the number of stored XML documents, `#Nodes` represents the number of XML nodes like elements, attributes, texts, etc.):

http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Statistics

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the answer @icza provided with the correct statistics for BaseX, I'd like to add a few things:

The upper limits on number of files, nodes, etc. pp. always apply **per database**. This means you can simply create another database to circumvent these restrictions. In many situations it might even be beneficial to split a large database up into several small ones, as locking is done on a database level, i.e. if you have one large database and you do a write, everything is locked. If you split it up into several databases, only a smaller portion will be locked.

As XQuery can easily access multiple databases in one query, split-up databases can easily be merged together in your queries.

Comment: you guys are right. But when i am trying to store   a million of records by using new add() method in java                   (like new Add(id,xmlFile).execute(context); ) it takes too long time even it is not ensure that records are stored. And it gives the error  Error:
"Database 'Trans' is being updated, or update was not completed."  when i am trying to see the xml files in BaseX database by command prompt. So is there any way to store the a million of records quickly?

Comment: well, you should definitely edit your question and show the appropriate code snippets (e.g. storeIntoBaseXDB), as your current snippet has nothing to do with it, actually. Also, what does "too long time" mean, how long is too long (inserting one million documents obviously takes some time). Additionally, as I told you many, many times now (here on SO and our mailing list): It would much likely be faster to use XQuery Update instead of serializing and writing the file to disk first.

Comment: i can't say how much time it will take, because when i try to store 100,000 records then it takes around an hour so i can't predict for a miilion(1,000,000) records.